# Any way to convert qcow2 to ovf?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, qemu, qcow2, ovf

In our application we are downloading a qcow2 image and after that we are supposed to import that as OVF.

So any way to convert `qcow2 --> OVF`   or `qcow2 --> vmdk(using qemu-img convert) --> ovf` .

Answer (score 8):

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vmdk whatever.qcow2 whatever.vmdk
```

Comment: Hi Chopper3 I want it in OVF format. Is that possible ?

Comment: That tool doesn't do it but once it's imported into vCenter as a vmdk you could then package it up into an .ova via file/export.