# Is there a way to convert qcow2 images to ovf format?

Tags: qcow2, ovf

I have one qcow2 image. But, I need image in ovf format. I know there is already one answer here [Any way to convert qcow2 to ovf?](https://serverfault.com/questions/604862/any-way-to-convert-qcow2-to-ovf), but I don't have vCenter installed with me. So, i am looking for any linux utility or some other way to convert?

Comment: http://ask.xmodulo.com/convert-ova-to-qcow2-linux.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ovf file is a desription file for your vm hardware. Number of CPUs, Memory, Disk Files, Network interfaces and no Disk Image.
It is the open form of a .vmx File.

You can't convert a disk image to a ovf.